# Tuple-like datatype in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

#### Background

I have the following pyspark dataframe

```
+-----+-----+
|key_1|key_2|
+-----+-----+
|True |True |
|False|True |
|False|False|
+-----+-----+
```

#### My Target

And I would like to create another column based on the value in key_1, and key_2 column as shown below.

```
+-----+-----+--------+
|key_1|key_2|combined|
+-----+-----+--------+
|True |True |  (1,2) |
|False|True |  (2,)  |
|False|False|  ()    |
+-----+-----+--------+
```

#### My Attemp and Question

I tried to iter over the columns

```py
combined = []
for row in df.rdd.collections():
    tmp = []
    if row[0] is True:
        tmp.append(1)
    if row[1] is True:
        tmp.append(2)
    combined.append(tuple(tmp))
```

Then I have the list `combined = [(1,2),(2,),()]`

How can I insert this `combined` list to create a new column in the same pyspark dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

#### sample data

```
sdf1 = sc.parallelize([[True, True],[False, True],[False, False]]).toDF(["key_1", "key_2"])
sdf1.show()
+-----+-----+
|key_1|key_2|
+-----+-----+
| true| true|
|false| true|
|false|false|
+-----+-----+
```

#### udf

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField("value_1", IntegerType()),
    StructField("value_2", IntegerType())
])

def get_tuple(key_1, key_2):
    if key_1:
        value_1 = 1
    else:
        value_1 = None
    if key_2:
        value_2 = 2
    else:
        value_2 = None
    return (value_1, value_2)

get_tuple_udf = udf(get_tuple, schema)
```

result

```
sdf1.withColumn("value", get_tuple_udf(sf.col("key_1"), sf.col("key_2"))).show()
+-----+-----+------+
|key_1|key_2| value|
+-----+-----+------+
| true| true|[1, 2]|
|false| true| [, 2]|
|false|false|   [,]|
+-----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sc.parallelize([[True, True],
                       [False, True],
                       [False, False]]
                     ).toDF(["key_1", "key_2"])

df = df.withColumn("value", F.array(F.when(F.col("key_1"), 1), F.when(F.col("key_2"), 2)))

>>> df.show()
+-----+-----+------+
|key_1|key_2| value|
+-----+-----+------+
| true| true|[1, 2]|
|false| true| [, 2]|
|false|false|   [,]|
+-----+-----+------+
```